Are these two words synonymous?
Are these two words always, never or sometimes synonymous?

כשיבואו
לכשיבואו


The words are almost identical, except for the extra ל.  Try giving more context to your question.  Where are you seeing these words and what about them are you trying to understand?
Without any context, the two words mean "when they come" and "for when they come".  Are those synonyms?
